# Function defined with generic types

Tags: arrays, scala

I searched for a while and I was not able to find a clear and satisfying answer to this question.

Suppose I have this little function to compute the mean value of an Array:

```
def meanofArray(s:Array[Double]) : Double = s.sum/s.length
```

the problem is that is Array **has** to be Double.
If for example I have this Array:

```
val x = Array( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 )
```

and make the call :

```
println(meanofArray(x))
```

I get the error found   : Array[Int]
                required: Array[Double]

How can I implement meanofArray so as to be able to accept any type of Int , Long , Float and Double with no errors ?

My thought was Generic types :

```
def meanofArray(s:Array[T]) : Double = s.sum/s.length
```

but I could not get it working.

Any other idea is welcomed !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are running into demonstrates the beauty of type abstraction.

Based solely on the signature of the function you provided

```
def meanofArray(s:Array[T]) : T
```

we know quite a bit about what this function can and can not do, as long as it does not do shady things like reflection of course. It can not do things like sort the Array, find the sum, etc. Based on some unfortunate characteristics of Scala, there are some things which we can not be sure it does not do, like use `equals` or `toString` for some `T`.

You need to declare some additional information about the type `T` in the function signature.

```
def meanofArray[T](s: Array[T])(implicit ev: Numeric[T]): Double
```

Here we are declaring that `T` must have a definition of [`Numeric[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric) defined and in scope at call sites. `Numeric[T]` provides the definitions of functions required in order to do the calculations you need. We are now declaring that this function may do more things like sort the array or find the sum.

And the implementation you are looking for...

```
def meanofArray[T](s: Array[T])(implicit ev: Numeric[T]): Double = 
  s.view.map(ev.toDouble).sum / s.length
```

EDIT: Map `s` to view of `Array[Double]` to decrease likelihood of overflow. Taken from @Eastsun's answer. Taking `Numeric[T]` implicitly is strongly preferred over implicit view from `T => Double` in my opinion though.

Comment: I can not fully understand your code but it seems that if values are Int then the return type is Int too which in our case is not always true. Moreover it does not work for doubles. So do you really have to make a bunch of different implementations to achieve my goal?

Comment: @DoomProg this answer is what you're looking for, though the return type should probably be `Double` rather than `T`.  This pattern allows you to define a generic function while still restricting it to numeric types, in this case all types `T` for which there is an implicit `Integral[T]` (which is provided by the standard library).

Comment: @DoomProg See my edit about the need to import `Integral[Double]` explicitly.

Comment: @DoomProg I updated once again in order to return `Double` instead of `T`. Doing this allows the function to take more general `Numeric` instead of `Integral`.

Comment: I see what you did. Your answer and @Eastsun 's were very enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want(The parameter's type of `mean` is `Seq[A]` so that you can use it as `mean(List(1, 2, 3))` or `mean("ABCDEFG")`):

```
scala> def mean[A](arr: Seq[A])(implicit view: A => Double): Double = 
         (arr map view sum) / arr.size
mean: [A](arr: Seq[A])(implicit view: A => Double)Double

scala> mean(Array(1, 2, 3, 4))
res0: Double = 2.5
```

Compare with @drstevens 's solution:

```
scala> def meanofArray[T](s: Array[T])(implicit ev: Numeric[T]): Double = 
     |   ev.toDouble(s.sum) / s.length
meanofArray: [T](s: Array[T])(implicit ev: scala.math.Numeric[T])Double

scala> meanofArray(Array[Byte](111, 111, 111, 111))
res3: Double = -17.0  //Wrong!!!

scala> mean((Array[Byte](111, 111, 111, 111)))
res4: Double = 111.0 //Right !!!
```

Comment: My answer is not technically wrong. In the case of byte, sum returns byte. The sum of the integers in your array, 444, overflows byte. Similar but possibly slightly different overflow issues will happen with all solutions to this.

Comment: Converting to Double before finding sum does certainly reduce the likelihood of this happening though. I have updated my answer to perform this conversion first before finding sum. I much prefer context to view bounds though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest solution i could come up for your question.

```
def mean[A <% Double : Numeric](seq:Seq[A]) = seq.sum/seq.length
```

Here, Seq.sum needs an evidence of A conforms to be a Numeric type. (`:` in the type parameter)
And that division to work, the result of `seq.sum` should be viewable as a Double. Altogether this results a result mean of `Double` type